# What was the most expensive war of the 20th century?

Tags: war, economy

Putting aside the enormous "cost" of wars in terms of human life and suffering, what about the economic costs? Once I studied the Vietnam war and Gabriel Kolko in one of his books described how much the Vietnam War cost the US in dollar terms.

So the shortlist:
World War One
World War Two 
Korean War
Vietnam War 
Gulf War

To keep it a bit simpler, my question is: which country spent the most money on a  war and which war was it? So the shortlist:

United States
England
Russia
Japan
Germany
Italy

Answers can use wars and countries not in these lists; there are other candidates.

Comment: Do you want the financial cost to one country or to many countries in the same war?

Comment: How can you compute the economic cost without taking in account the human cost, when such human cost have a major impact on the economy ? Have so much young men dead and so much wounded people has a major impact on the economy, as there is a lack of working force and as such production power. It's impossible to separate both when there's huge deathtoll such as the World Wars.

Comment: Comment deleted for violation of community standards.

Comment: Which inflation adjuster, and what kind of purchasing power parity system do you want to use? Those may well determine the answer.

Comment: Are you only counting costs accrued during the war, or also direct long-term costs? For example, do you count Germany losing the eastern half of its GDP for ~45 years (or vice versa, East Germany losing its western half) part of the costs for WWII? It seems like you'd either need to put so many constraints on this question that the answer becomes trivial, or leave it open-ended and be too broad.

Comment: I find this question novel if it can be limited to the resources spent by a country during a war.

Comment: Sad that complex, valid questions are 'too broad". Clearly people just want history to be a book by the Hardy Boys. Throughout SE I have found taht the reading and comprehension skills of people are far worse than they were in my pre internet generation 30 years ago.

Comment: Too broad is a poor close reason here, but it's not unreasonable to ask if you can provide a clearer way to define the question.